# windows Service running on multiple servers

Tags: sql-server-2005, c#-4.0, windows-services

In my application I am running a windows service on a Webserver.
This service calls a single table and select and update the table.
When this service is deployed on multiple webservers, How can I prevent 
deadlocks on the table from this service running on multiple webservers.
What happens, when this table is accessed by 2 services from different 
webservers same time ?.
What are the other neccessary precautions I need to take.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database handles locking within a transaction for you. What you need to do is to ensure that

1. All associated operations occur within a transaction.
2. You have the right transaction isolation level.

If you read data, wait for some user input and then do the update you have to decide whether do use *optimistic* or *pessimistic* concurrency control.